# How to highlight a specific table cell in material UI table in react based on a text search

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have implemented a Material UI table and forming up the table based on the array of objects.
For example my array of objects:

```
[{id:1, name:abc, age: 12},{id:2, name:def, age: 13},{id:3, name:ghi, age: 14}].
```

This is my code for generating the table using material-ui for react.

```
return (
<div className={classes.root}>
       {data.name}
  <Paper className={classes.paper}>
    <EnhancedTableToolbar handleSearch={handleSearch} value={searchValue} />
    <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
      <Table
        className={classes.table}
        aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
        stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table"
      >
        <EnhancedTableHead
          classes={classes}
          order={order}
          orderBy={orderBy}
          onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
        />
        <TableBody>
          {displaySortedData(data, getComparator(order, orderBy))
            .map((row, index) => {
              return (
                <TableRow
                  hover
                  tabIndex={-1}
                  key={row.ID}
                >
                  <TableCell style={{ textAlign: "center", cursor: "pointer" }}>
                    <EditIcon />
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row" align="right">
                    {row.ID}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left"><span className={row.name.match(searchValue) ? classes.tableCell : "" }>{row.SOR_NAME}</span></TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">{row.age}</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  </Paper>

</div>


);
```

Now whenever user type in search box i capture that in **searchValue**. Based on the searchValue i change the array of objects and display the table. Now i need to highlight the text too in the table for the searched text. 
For that i compare the search value in the 4rth table cell as you can see above in the code.
But my issue is that it highlights the entire column and not just the single table cell in which it found the exact search match. I understand as i am writing the comparison in the tableCell, that is why it highlights the entire column. But i only want to highlight a specific cell of that table if it exactly matches the searched text.

The EnhancedTableHead returns the table headers.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for highlighting the table cell and not the word. For example if user types "match" in search field. Then with the help of following function it highlights the table cell but doesnt highlight the actual characters of the word. For example if in a table cell the word "MatchingWord", it will highlight the full word but not just "Match" in "MatchingWord"

```
 const highlight = (classes, rowValues) =>{
    if(searchValue == null || searchValue == "" || rowValues == null || rowValues == "") {
      return classes.notMatchingTableCell 
    } else if(rowValues.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase()) == true) {
    return classes.tableCell
    }
    return classes.notMatchingTableCell 


    }
```

Here classes i pass is the actual css class for higlighting. And rowValues is the value of the row for that object. So in the material ui table part add this function in  tag like this

```
<TableCell align="left"><span className= {highlight(classes, row.age)}>{row.age}</span></TableCell>
```

Comment: This works because we change the css of the table cell if it finds the matching word. Even if its partially matching, it highlights the full cell.

Comment: I dont know if it could be changed to just highlight a part of the word.